# Assertion of zero int to int32

Tags: go

I noticed that Go assertion doesn't work as I expect for zero int. Here is the code:

```
var i interface{}
i = 0
i32, ok := i.(int32)
fmt.Println(ok)
fmt.Println(i32)
```

The output is following:

```
false
0
```

I can't find an explanation of this behavior. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a bug, it's a well defined behavior.

This line:

```
i = 0
```

Is an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments), and you use the untyped `0` integer constant to assign to `i`. Since a (concrete) type is needed to carry out the assignment (and `i`s type being `interface{}` does not define one), the default type of that untyped constant will be used which is `int`. Read [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants):

> The answer is that an untyped constant has a default type, an implicit type that it transfers to a value if a type is needed where none is provided.

You can verify it if you modify it like this:

```
i2, ok := i.(int)
fmt.Println(ok)
fmt.Println(i2)
```

Which outputs:

```
true
0
```

If you would use a typed constant:

```
i = int32(0)
```

Then yes, the stored value would be of type `int32`, and you would get the same output:

```
i = int32(0)
i32, ok := i.(int32)
fmt.Println(ok)
fmt.Println(i32)
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5hWG0hyTCS1).

Answer (score 5):

`i` doesn't contain an `int32`, it contains an `int`, and so the type assertion fails.

Assigning a literal value directly to an `interface{}` like this or using one in a short variable declaration can be a bit confusing because you don't really get to see what type of value you get; you need to know the rules for the ["default type"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) of a constant. If this gives you trouble, you can explicitly cast it to a type, like
`i = int32(0)`, which will ensure that `i` does in fact contain an `int32`.